# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITYANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, iis

When my computer is running my `Web Application` on `IIS` the connection to the DataBase(sqlServer) works, but on the other hand when i try to run it from another computer (not running the iis) it throws this exeption : `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITYANONYMOUS LOGON'.`can someone help me on this? im not very experienced on this topic.
Edit:Im Using Windows authentication (impersonate = true)
here is the connection string:`Data Source=XXXXX\APP; Initial Catalog=cebi; Integrated Security=True`

Comment: Your connection string is probably wrong. Please add it to your question so we can help you.

Comment: @KobyDouek  but when i run the aplication on the computer running iis it works properly, the problem comes when i try to open it from another computer. but i can add the connection string if you guys think that there may be a problem there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit:Im Using Windows authentication (`impersonate = true`) here is the connection string:`Data Source=XXXXX\APP; Initial Catalog=cebi; Integrated Security=True`

Your domain administrator needs to set up [Kerberos Constrained Delegation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg723715.aspx) for IIS. Some blogs describing this more friendly:

- [Setting up Kerberos Authentication for a Website in IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/)
- [Kerberos Constrained Delegation with ASP.NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2017/01/13/constrained-kerberos-delegation-with-asp-net/)

Comment: but i dont have permission to "mess" with active directory here, is this the only way to do it? sry im not very experienced at this and its the first time i heard of "Kerberos"

Comment: That's why I told you that you need to ask the **domain administrator** to do this for you. there is absolutely, positively, no other way.